# Прокрутка содержимого модального окна

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js

есть функция которая закрывает модальное окно и тут же открывает новое
Но проблема в том, что новое окно с большим содержанием контента и оно открывается, но прокрутка содержимого не доступна.Хотя когда просто это окно открывают через стандартную кнопку

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Запустить модальное окно
</button>
```

окно с прокруткой открывается корректно...

```
closeModal(){
  $('#addNew').modal('hide');
  $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение вопроса 
overflow-y: auto;